# Twitter Bootstrap: Multi-layered dropdown?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am writing an audio message web application for a church. I would like a dropdown that has "Old Testament" and "New Testament" which respectively show their books; so I have all of the books in both testaments in a dropdown which is harder to read and navigate.

Take a look here: http://cstonecc.net/audio.php

Answer (score 1):

http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#dropdowns

> Add `.dropdown-submenu` to any `li` in an existing dropdown menu for automatic styling.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li class="dropdown-submenu>
        <a tabindex ="-1" href="#">Old Testament</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>...</li>
            <li>...</li>
            <li>...</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
        <a tabindex="-1" href="#">New Testament</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>...</li>
            <li>...</li>
            <li>...</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for. My blind eyes missed it! xP